# Fieldset dinámico se traba al hacer una validación

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo unos fieldsets que funcionan dinámicamente mediante una una animación, el problema es que no cuando hago la validacion mediante el controlador, los botones de abajo que son next y previous se trancan y debo refrescar la pantalla

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        {include file="require/cssRequire.tpl"}
        {include file="signup/css2.tpl"}
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--  GLobal -->
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$urlApi}}" id="api"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$urlImg}}" id="img"/>
        {include file="layout/menu3.tpl"}
        <!-- MultiStep Form -->
        <div class="row">

        <div class="menuApp">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
            <a><b>REGISTRO DE CLIENTE</b></a>
        </nav>
        </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-3">
                <form id="msform" autocomplete="off" id="formSignUp">
                    <!-- progressbar -->
              <!--      <ul id="progressbar">
                        <li class="active">Datos Personales</li>
                        <li>Datos Contacto</li> 
                        <li>Datos administrativos</li> 
                        <li>Datos Contactos</li> -->
                    </ul>
                    <!-- fieldsets -->
                    <fieldset id="fs1">  <!-- Primer fieldset -->
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Crear usuario</h2>
                    <div id="subtitle1" style="display: inline-block;">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">eMail *</h3>
                        <input type="email" autocomplete="new-Email_principal" id="Email_principal" name="Email_principal" required placeholder="Email Principal">
                    </div>
                    <div id="subtitle2" style="display: inline-block; padding:20px;">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Contraseña *</h3>
                        <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" placeholder="Contraseña" require/>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    </br>
                        <input type="button" name="next" id="next1" class="next action-button" value="Siguiente"/>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset id="fs2">  <!-- Segundo fieldset -->
                        <h2 class="fs-title">Datos Personales</h2>

                        <center>

                    <div id="subtitle1" style="display: inline-block; padding:40px;">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Primer Nombre *</h3>
                        <input type="text" style="width: 90%;" name="Primer_nombre" id="Primer_nombre" required placeholder="Primer Nombre"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="subtitle2" style="display: inline-block; padding:40px;">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Segundo Nombre </h3>
                        <input type="text" style="width: 90%;" name="Segundo_nombre" id="Segundo_nombre" required placeholder="Segundo Nombre"/>
                    </div>
                    
                        <input type="hidden" value="16" id="Id_zona" name="Id_zona"/>
                        <input type="hidden" value="18" id="Id_centro" name="Id_centro"/>
                        <input type="hidden" autocomplete="new-Tokenusuario" id="Tokenusuario" name="Tokenusuario" value="{$token}">
                    
                    <div id="subtitle3" style="display: inline-block; padding:40px;">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Primer Apellido *</h3>
                        <input type="text" style="width: 90%;" name="Primer_apellido" id="Primer_apellido" required placeholder="Primer Apellido"/>
                    </div>

                    </center>

                    <div id="subtitle4">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle" id="sec_apellido">Segundo Apellido</h3>
                        <input type="text" name="Segundo_apellido" id="Segundo_apellido"  placeholder="Segundo Apellido"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="subtitle5">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Cedula de identidad *</h3>
                        <input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="width: 90%;" name="Cedula" id="Cedula" placeholder="No. Identidad"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="subtitle6">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Sexo *</h3>
                       <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="Id_hombre" value="1" onclick="getResults();"><label id="Hombre">Hombre</label>
                       <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="Id_mujer" value="2" onclick="getResults();"><label id="Mujer">Mujer</label>
                    </div>

                     <div id="subtitle7">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fecha de nacimiento *</h3>
                        <input
                            autocomplete="off"
                            type="text"
                            name="Fecha_nacimiento"
                            id="Fecha_nacimiento"
                            placeholder="Seleccione una fecha de nacimiento"
                            value="01/01/1970" style="width: 90%;"
                            /></td>
                            </tr>
                        
                        <input type="hidden" id="Id_sexo" name="Id_sexo" value=""/>
                    </div>
                            

                        <center>

                        <br></br>
                        <input type="button" name="previous1" id="previous1" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previo"/>
                        <input type="button" name="next" id="next2" class="next action-button" value="Siguiente"/>
                        </center>

                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset id="fs3">  <!-- Tercer fieldset -->
                    <center>
                     <h2 class="fs-title">Datos de contacto</h2>

                    <div id="subtitle1" style="display: inline-block; padding:50px;">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">País *</h3>
                        <select style="width:100%;"
                        class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb mb-2"
                        id="Id_pais"
                        name="Id_pais"
                        required="required"
                        onchange="seleccionarCiudadPais()">
                            <option
                            value=""
                            selected
                            style="display: none;">Pais
                            </option>
                            {foreach from=$paisesList item=result}
                            <option
                            value="{$result['id_pais']}">
                                {$result['nombre_pais']}
                            </option>
                            {/foreach}
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div id="subtitle2" style="display: inline-block; padding:50px;">
                    <h3 class="fs-subtitle" style="text-align:center">Ciudad *</h3>
                    <select class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb mb-2" 
                            id="Id_ciudad" name="Id_ciudad" required="required" onchange="seleccionarZonaCiudad()">
                            <option
                            value=""
                            selected
                            style="display: none; width:auto; min-width: 150px;">Seleccione una Ciudad
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <br></br>
                    <div id="subtitle1" style="display: inline-block; padding:50px;">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Dirección *</h3>
                       <input type="text" name="Direccion" id="Direccion"  placeholder="Dirección"></input>
                    </div>

                    <div id="subtitle2" style="display: inline-block; padding:50px;">
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Teléfono *</h3>
                       <input type="number" name="Telefono" id="Telefono" required="required" onchange="myChangeFunction(Telefono)"  placeholder="0424111211"/>
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" id="Movil" name="Movil"/>
                    <input type="hidden" id="Email_secundario" name="Email_secundario" value=""/>

                        </center>

                        <center>
                        <br></br>
                         <input type="button" name="previous2" id="previous2"  class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previo"/>
                         <input type="button" name="next" id="next3" class="next action-button" value="Siguiente"/>
                        </center>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset id="fs4">
                    <center>
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Otros datos</h2>
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><h3 class="fs-subtitle" style="text-align:center">Patologia o dolencia (Alguna operacion o problema de salud notable, como un dolor de espalda)</h3></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </center>
                     
                        <input type="text" name="Fisico" id="Fisico" placeholder="Patologia o dolencia"/>

                    <br></br>
                    <center>
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;"><h3 class="fs-subtitle" style="text-align: center;">Referencia *</h3></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;"><p>¿Cómo se entero de nosotros?</p>
                         <select onChange="scheduleA(value)"
                         class="form-control form-control-dropdown form-control-dropdown-bb" 
                         name="Id_referido_tipo" 
                         id="Id_referido_tipo">

                        {foreach from=$infoReferidoTipo item=resultadoReferidoTipo}
                        <option
                        value="{$resultadoReferidoTipo['id_referido_tipo']}">
                        {$resultadoReferidoTipo['tipo_referencia']}
                        </option>
                        {/foreach}
                        </select><td>

                    <td style="text-align:center; padding-left:30px;"><div id="Referencia">
                        <p>Referido por (Código)</p>
                        <input type="text" name="Referido" id="Referido"  autocomplete="off" value="{$token2}" placeholder="Codigo de referido"/>
                        </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </center>
                    <br></br>
                    <input type="button" name="previous3" id="previous3" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previo"/>
                    <input type="button" name="submit" id="next4" class="next action-button" value="Registrar"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.MultiStep Form -->
        {include file="require/jsRequire.tpl"}
        {include file="signup/js2.tpl"}
    </body>
</html>
```

Este es el tpl con los javascript. El $("#next") es donde está el código que corre las validaciones entre las páginas

```
{literal}
    <script>
    //DatePicker
     $('#Fecha_nacimiento').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
        weekStart: 0,
        time: false,
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    });
    //DatePicker
    //jQuery time
    var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
    var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
    var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

        function scheduleA(value) {
        var element=document.getElementById('Referencia');
        if(value=='1' || value=='4' || value=='5'){
            element.style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('Referido').value = ''; //Borrar el referido
            document.getElementById('Referido').innerHTML = '';
        }else{
            element.style.display='none';
        }
        }

        function getResults() {
        var testVar;
        var radios = document.getElementsByName("sexo");
        for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            testVar = (radios[i].value);
            document.getElementById("Id_sexo").value = testVar;
            break;
            }
         }
        }

        function myChangeFunction(Telefono) {
                var input2 = document.getElementById('Movil');
                input2.value = Telefono.value;
        }

        if ($(window).width() < 500) {
            $("#Primer_nombre").attr("placeholder", "Nombre");
            $("#Segundo_nombre").attr("placeholder", "Nombre");
            $("#Primer_apellido").attr("placeholder", "Apellido"); 
            $("#Segundo_apellido").attr("placeholder", "Apellido");
            $("#Cedula").attr("placeholder", "Cedula");
            $("#Referido").attr("placeholder", "Codigo");
        }

    $("#next1").click(function(){
        if(!document.getElementById("Email_principal").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo de email es requerido", "error");
        if(!document.getElementById("Password").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo de contraseña es requerido", "error");
        if(animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        datos = $("#Email_principal").serializeArray();
        datos.push({ name: "opcion", value: "revisarEmail" });
            jQuery
        .ajax({
        url: "../controllers/usuarioController.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: datos,
        })
        .done(function (data) {
        let success = JSON.parse(data).success;
        let msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;
        let result = JSON.parse(data).result;
        if (success) {
            swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");
        }else{
            cambiarpag1();
        }
        });
    });

    function cambiarpag1(){
        current_fs = $('#fs1');
        next_fs = $('#fs2');

            //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

            //show the next fieldset
            next_fs.show();
            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                left = (now * 50)+"%";
                //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({
            'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
            'position': 'absolute'
            });
                next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function(){
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    }

    function cambiarpag2(){
        current_fs = $('#fs2');
        next_fs = $('#fs3');

            //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

            //show the next fieldset
            next_fs.show();
            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                left = (now * 50)+"%";
                //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({
            'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
            'position': 'absolute'
            });
                next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function(){
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    }

    function cambiarpag3(){
        current_fs = $('#fs3');
        next_fs = $('#fs4');

        //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

        //show the next fieldset
        next_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                left = (now * 50)+"%";
                //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({
            'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
            'position': 'absolute'
        });
                next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function(){
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    }

    function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}

    $("#next2").click(function(){
        if(!document.getElementById("Primer_nombre").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo de primer nombre es requerido", "error");
        if(!document.getElementById("Primer_apellido").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo primer apellido es requerido", "error");
        if(!document.getElementById("Id_sexo").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo sexo es requerido", "error");
        if(!document.getElementById("Cedula").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo cedula es requerido", "error");
        if(!document.getElementById("Fecha_nacimiento").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo de fecha de nacimiento es requerido", "error");
        if(animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        datos = $("#Cedula").serializeArray();
        datos.push({ name: "opcion", value: "revisarCedula" });
            jQuery
        .ajax({
        url: "../controllers/usuarioController.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: datos,
        })
        .done(function (data) {
        let success = JSON.parse(data).success;
        let msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;
        let result = JSON.parse(data).result;
        if (success) {
            swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");
        }else{
            cambiarpag2();
        }
        });

    });


    $("#next3").click(function(){
    if(!document.getElementById("Id_pais").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo pais es requerido", "error");
    if(!document.getElementById("Id_ciudad").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo de ciudad es requerido", "error");
    if(!document.getElementById("Telefono").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo de teléfono es requerido", "error");
        if(animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        datos = $("#Telefono").serializeArray();
        datos.push({ name: "opcion", value: "revisarTelefono" });
            jQuery
        .ajax({
        url: "../controllers/usuarioController.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: datos,
        })
        .done(function (data) {
        let success = JSON.parse(data).success;
        let msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;
        let result = JSON.parse(data).result;
        if (success) {
            swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");
        }else{
            cambiarpag3();
        }
        });
    });

    $("#previous1").click(function(){
        if(animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        current_fs = $('#fs2');
        previous_fs = $('#fs1');

        //de-activate current step on progressbar
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

        //show the previous fieldset
        previous_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
                scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
                left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
                //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({'left': left});
                previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function(){
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    });

        $("#previous2").click(function(){
        if(animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        current_fs = $('#fs3');
        previous_fs = $('#fs2');

        //de-activate current step on progressbar
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

        //show the previous fieldset
        previous_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
                scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
                left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
                //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({'left': left});
                previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function(){
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    });

       $("#previous3").click(function(){
        if(animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        current_fs = $('#fs4');
        previous_fs = $('#fs3');

        //de-activate current step on progressbar
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

        //show the previous fieldset
        previous_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
                scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
                left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
                //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({'left': left});
                previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function(){
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    });

    //Formulario SignUp
    $("#next4").click(function(){

    datos = $("form").serializeArray();
    datos.push({ name: "opcion", value: "addCliente" });
    console.log(datos);

    jQuery
        .ajax({
        url: "../controllers/usuarioController.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: datos,
        })
        .done(function (data) {
        let success = JSON.parse(data).success;
        let msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;
        let result = JSON.parse(data).result;
        if (success) {
            swal("¡Realizado!", "Se ha registrado satisfactoriamente", "success").then((value) => {
                location.href = "login.php";
            });
        } else {
            swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");
        }
        });
    });

    </script>
{/literal}
```

Estos son los códigos de UsuarioController relevantes, voy a colocar uno porque los demás son iguales y todos tienen el mismo bug

```
function __construct()   

{

    if($opcion == 'revisarCedula'){

        foreach ($_POST as $nombre => $valor) {

            $datos[$nombre] = htmlentities($valor);

            $datos[$nombre] = html_entity_decode($datos[$nombre]); 

        }

        self::checkCedula($datos);

    }
```

}

```
public function checkCedula($datos){
    $usuario = new usuarioModel;
    $json = array();

    if($usuario->revisarcedula($datos) == true){
        $json['msj'] = 'Error . Esa cedula ya existe'; 
        $json['success'] = true; 
        echo json_encode($json);
    }else{
        $json['success'] = false; 
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
}
```

Aqui esta un ejemplo del proceso que hace el modelo

```
public static function revisarcedula($datos){

    require '../require/Conexion.php';

    $Cedula = $datos['Cedula'];

    $sql = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM ec_usuario AS us WHERE (us.cedula = '".$Cedula."')
    ";

    $result = @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);// or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if (!$result) {

           return null;

    }

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    mysqli_close ($mysqli);

    return $row;

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa que los botones *se trancan*?

Comment: Dejan de funcionar si la validacion de que se encontró un dato duplicado sale como true, si no ocurre esa validación fluye todo normal

Comment: ¿Qué significa *dejan de funcionar*? ¿No reaccionan a los clicks, aparecen como desactivados, desaparecen, da error, explota la pantalla :)? Perdona que sea pesado, no estamos frente a tu pantalla por tanto debes explicar con claridad lo que ocurre.

Comment: No reaccionan a los clicks, como si estuvieran deshabilitados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la variable `animating` no cambia a falso cuando hay errores porque no se ejecuta la animación y, por tanto, tampoco la función callback de `complete:`, que es donde se restablece.

Cambiando un poco la lógica:

1. La primera validación debe ser si se está ejecutando la animación
2. No modifiques la variable en la función del evento `click`, sino donde realmente se ejecuta la animación
3. No repitas código, es mejor simplificar

```
$("#next1").click(function(){
    // Esta debe ser la primera validación
    if(animating) return false;
    if(!document.getElementById("Email_principal").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo de email es requerido", "error");
    if(!document.getElementById("Password").value.trim()) return swal("¡Error!","El campo de contraseña es requerido", "error");

    // No poner animating en verdadero aquí, porque no es donde debe ir

    datos = $("#Email_principal").serializeArray();
    datos.push({ name: "opcion", value: "revisarEmail" });
        jQuery
    .ajax({
    url: "../controllers/usuarioController.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: datos,
    })
    .done(function (data) {
    let success = JSON.parse(data).success;
    let msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;
    let result = JSON.parse(data).result;
    if (success) {
        swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");
    }else{
        cambiarpag1();
    }
    });
});
```

Todo el código para mostrar el elemento activo se repite en cada función de cambio de página, puedes simplificarlo creando otra función:

```
function cambiarpag1(){
    current_fs = $('#fs1');
    next_fs = $('#fs2');
    animarPag();
}
function cambiarpag2(){
    current_fs = $('#fs2');
    next_fs = $('#fs3');
    animarPag();
}
function animarPag() {
    // La animación se está ejecutando, aquí es donde se cambia la variable
    animating = true;

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
        });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        },
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó